# JUnit how to compare an object to an array?

Tags: java, junit

The code below is an instance of Object which is essentially an array of strings:

```
private final Map<String, Object> tokenPayload = // assume map is populated
tokenPayload.get("aud") // gives me instance of Object
```

It's essentially a JWT that has an aud claim that looks like this:

```
{
  "aud": [
    "https://www.example.com"
  ],
}
```

And I'm trying to add a simple JUnit assert:

```
assertArrayEquals(new String[] {"https://www.example.com"}, (Object[])tokenPayload.get("aud"));
```

but I'm getting a cast exception `ClassCast class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; (java.util.ArrayList and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

What is the best way to test this?

Comment: As tokenPayload.get("aud") return an ArrayList convert to an Array, tokenPayload.get("aud").toArray()

Comment: @Briggo do you mind sharing an example

Comment: `(Object[]) <Object>` is a bad cast, as it may lead to kind of unwanted behaviour and errors. When you are parsing Json i reccomend you use libraries like [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson) instead of reading to map with objects.
And to use List instead of Array if possible - not `Object[]` but `ArrayList<Object>`.

Comment: @RobertO'Neal, when you read an array from a json in Java it is an ArrayList under the hood. So just change `Object[]` to ArrayList<Object>.
You may also want to use hamcrest matchers to assert lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example including assertion using Hamcrest as mentioned by ip.java

```
    @Test
    public void testArrayComparison() throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"aud\": [\"https://www.example.com\",\"https://www.example.biz\"]}";

        Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Map.class);

        List<Object> aud = (List<Object>) map.get("aud");

        Object[] expected = new Object[] {"https://www.example.biz","https://www.example.com"};

        assertThat(aud, containsInAnyOrder(expected));
    }
```